# Firebase import not recognized with TypeScript + Rollup

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, rollupjs

I'm importing Firebase [as a module](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?hl=nl#using-module-bundlers) in a TypeScript app. However, I can't get the import to be recognized correctly. I'm using es6 imports and everything seems to be correct, but I must be missing something obvious (a bit new to TypeScript).

Branch: https://github.com/askibinski/paratrooper/tree/firebase

The import is [here](https://github.com/askibinski/paratrooper/blob/firebase/src/index.ts#L13).

Reproduce:

- `npm i`
- `npm run build` (rollup build)
- open index.html, see error in console (Chrome):

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Comment: https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/node-resolve

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm also new to rollup. With that plugin AND changing the import to "import firebase from "firebase/app";" AND adding the allowSyntheticDefaultImports flag in tsconfig, I got it working!
If you create an answer, I'll confirm it.